# How to ask a web page to show desktop website using Ubuntu Web Browser?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, browser, websites

There doesn't seem to be a button on Ubuntu's web browser to ask a website to show the desktop version of their site; it seems fixed to a mobile website.

How can I browse desktop websites on the Ubuntu web browser?

(Usuing Ubuntu Touch OTA-12 on LG Nexus 4)

Comment: It's a long-standing feature request: http://pad.lv/1377033. Who knows when they're going to include this?!

Answer (score -2):

Generally that's not a feature of the browser. Most websites offer the option to show their Desktop version, mostly at the bottom of the page.